# Cross-domain Ajax POST and user verification

Tags: python, ajax, django

I'm working on app which saves things from many cross domains via Ajax POST method to my server/app. I need to find a solution how to send a POST and verify if the user who sent it is already signed on my site and than save it to the database.

I am pretty sure that I need Chrome, Firefox extension to do it, because I need to embed my js on every page my users surf on. The thing is I don't know where to start and how should it work. I could set up proxy to make JSON POST work, but I don't know how to verify if the user is signed on my site.

Should I get cookies of my users from browser via Chrome API and sent it in the POST and authenticate the cookie/session in Django? What do you suggest?

Thank you for your help. I appreciate every hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user logons at http://yourserver.com, you can set a permanent cookie to identify him. (see `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE` and `COOKIE_AGE` variables in django)

Then, when he embeds any JS from another site from yourserver.com domain, the cookies are automatically sent for this domain, and you can check on your django side for the cookie existence and validity and give the good JS.

Because of crossdomain issues, you should better use form POST as an alternative as AJAX as it is not security restricted. You can then [play with iframes and javascript to make both domains communicates](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes).

To embed the JS in another website, you can use a browser extension, or a simple [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet), which will load your code in the current page when the user clicks it from any webpage.

My 2 cents;

Comment: What about the situation when JS is hosted on CDN? It's going to be high-load app and this will generate a lot of requests.

Comment: you can have the main scripts at the CDN and just the variable part served dynamically.

Comment: What about 3-legged OAuth? My JS will comunicate with Chrome, Firefox extension and if the extension OAuth is not authorized on server's side they will have to sign in eventually and authorize it. Is it possible to send data to my server through my (authorized) extension?

Comment: Yes your extension can send what you want to your server